# Hard drive is not bootable after running Windows Verifier

Tags: windows-7, boot

I followed this guide: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/101379-driver-verifier-enable-disable.html

After the computer restarted, it blue screened and now I am unable to boot the operating system. I cannot even boot HP's system recovery. This is an HP laptop. What should i do at this point?

Comment: Can you boot in safe mode? What happens when you try? What error do you get?

Comment: No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key.

Comment: Probably your enabling of windows verifier is just coincidence then. This seems like a hardware problem with the hard drive. Did you do anything else at all?